# ActiveMQ Event and NMSCorrelationID

Tags: c#, events, activemq-classic

I've been using the following code for Listening to a message over a specific Queue, and it works fine. However, I wouldn't want an event to be triggered every time a new message arrives on the Queue, rather, I would like to be triggered for only those messages with a specific NMSCorrelationID.

Is there a way to trigger the MessageListener Event only if a certain NMSCorrelationID exists?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(activeMQ_URL);                    
IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection(activeMQ_Username, activeMQ_Password);
ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.IndividualAcknowledge); 
IDestination destination = session.GetQueue(queue);                                     
IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination);                        
connection.Start();                                                                     
consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(OnMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JMS selector to filter only messages that match a given correlation ID by creating the consumer with a selector along the lines or "JMSCorrelationID='ID:X'".  Depending on how your messages are getting tagged that could work or you could employ some scheme to add message properties to select on and do it that way.